# After calling removeFromSuperview "interfacebuilded" objects are gone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a normal Interace in interface builder (there's a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`). In code, I create a `UIScrollView` with a (unknown) number of `UILabels` (depends by the User). These labels are created in `- (void)viewWillAppear` to make sure the data is up to date. To remove the labels, in `viewWillDisappear` i'm calling

```
for(UIView *subview in [scrollView  subviews])
{
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The problem is, after the view get's called again, the Objects created with interfacebuilder (the `UILabel` & `UIButton`) disappear. Do the get removed by calling `[subview removeFromSuperview];`? If yes, how to add them again? Everything which is created by code is still there…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add tag to your labels that you add dynamically.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc...];
  label.tag = 999999;
}
```

then.

```
for(UIView *subview in [scrollView  subviews])
{
   if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && subview.tag == 999999){
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is working. Thanks a lot! You guys are really awesome, I've learned so much :)

Comment: I tried to, but theres a box "You can accept an answer in 38 seconds". I'll just try it again later!

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove all subviews. Remove only the labels you added in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I can't. The Labels are created in for(int i = 0; i < n; i++). So I have "myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame(CGRectMake(x,y(44*i), widght, height));
So if I would remove the label from superview, only ONE Label would disappear, because the other ones are already "overwritten"...

Comment: See the answer of janusfidel how to remove only the labels.

Answer (score 0):

UILabel, UIButton and UITextfields are basically subclasses of UIView.
So if you remove all the UIViews under the scrollview, it will also remove them too.

```
for (UIView *myView in [scrollView  subviews]) {
    if([myView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
        [myView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if([myView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        [myView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if([myView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
        [myView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```